# MDX query designer giving null values in column

Tags: sql-server, null, mdx

I am using report builder to create MDX query and for some reason one of the columns is showing null values. I know there is data for that column but not sure why MDX is giving nulls.

Can anyone help with this issue please? This is my query:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Premium LCL] } ON COLUMNS, 
  NON EMPTY { (
    [D_BU].[Business Unit Number].[Business Unit Number].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [D_Policy].[OriginalPolicyID].[OriginalPolicyID].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [D_Revenue_Attribute].[InsurerName].[InsurerName].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [D_Client].[ClientName].[ClientName].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [D_TransactionDate].[Accounting Month Number].[Accounting Month Number].ALLMEMBERS *    [D_TransactionDate].[Accounting Year].[Accounting Year].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [D_TransactionDate].[Accounting Month Year].[Accounting Month Year].ALLMEMBERS *    [D_PolicyExpirationDate].[Expiration Month Year].[Expiration Month Year].ALLMEMBERS *   [D_Policy].[InceptionDate].[InceptionDate].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [D_Product].[Product Line].[Product Line].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [D_Product].[Product Coverage].[Product Coverage].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [D_BU].[Region Name].[Region Name].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [D_BU].[Branch Name].[Branch Name].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [D_CarrierPayee].[Placement Market Group].[Placement Market Group].ALLMEMBERS *     [D_Industry_SIC].[SIC Level 2 Name].[SIC Level 2 Name].ALLMEMBERS *     
    [D_Industry_SIC].[SIC Level 3 Name].[SIC Level 3 Name].ALLMEMBERS 
       ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION ON ROWS 
FROM 
       ( 
    SELECT 
        ( 
            {[D_BU].[RegionName].&[GGB UK - Underwriting], 
            [D_BU].[RegionName].&[GGB UK - Specialty], 
            [D_BU].[RegionName].&[GGB(UK & Ireland)] } 
        ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM 
    ( 
     SELECT 
        ( 
            -{ [D_BU].[BranchName].&[Re Centre], 
            [D_BU].[BranchName].&[UK&Ireland] } 
        ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM 
    ( 
     SELECT 
        ( 
            { [D_TransactionDate].[Accounting Year].&[2019] : null} 
        ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM    
    [Model]
))) 
WHERE ( [D_BU].[RegionName].CurrentMember ) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE
```

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983)

Comment: which column is NULL ?